# How to get network traffic statistics?

Tags: java, netty

I'm using Netty 3.5.4.Final.

How can one get the number of inbound and outbound transferred bytes within a single netty client/server instance? Current or average upload/download speed would be nice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `org.jboss.netty.handler.traffic` provides the classes you need. You could install a `GlobalTrafficShapingHandler` (read and write limitation = 0) in your pipeline to measure throughput and the number of bytes that went through your pipeline.